# jooreports cambiar formato a una palabra específica en un texto

Tags: xml, pdf

estoy trabajando en un pdf personalizado hecho a partir de un xml en el que se contienen los datos y usando una plantilla odt hecha en LibreOffice.

Estoy cargando en la plantilla odt una lista de textos con las siguientes sentencias freemarker:

```
[#list liTextos as elTexto]
    ${elTexto.teTexto}
[/#list]
```

Y estoy cargando los textos de esta lista en un xml con la siguiente forma:

```
<liTextos>
    <elTexto>
        <teTexto>...dsadassd exampleWord sdsdasdsadasd...</teTexto>
    </elTexto>
    <elTexto>
        <teTexto>...urgergjuj exampleWord yujfggfergege...</teTexto>
    </elTexto>
    ....
</liTextos>
```

Bien, lo que necesito es dar formto a una palabra en concreto dentro de los párrafos, en este caso la palabra sería "exampleWord".

He creado en mi plantilla odt un estilo de texto llamado "textBold".

Necesito una manera de asignar dinámicamente el estilo "textBold" a la palabra "exampleWord". La forma de hacerlo dinámico sería meter el estilo desde el código que genera el xml y no desde el odt. He intentado hacerlo usando un replace en el código C que uso para cargar el xml, de la siguiente forma:

```
replace ("exampleWord", "<text:span text:style-name=\"textBold\">exampleWord</text:span>");
```

He intentado también hacer el replace dentro del propio odt con la siguiente sentencia freemarker:

```
${elTexto.teTexto?replace("exampleWord", "**exampleWord**")}
```

y tambien de la siguiente forma:

```
${elTexto.tetexto?replace('exampleWord', '<text:span text:style-name="textBold">exampleWord</text:span>')}
```

Pero de ninguna me funciona.

He leido que exampleWord son las etiquetas que se ponen a un determinado texto para darle formato, pero no me funciona de ninguna de las dos maneras, lo único que consigo es que en el pdf me aparezca esta cadena escrita literalmente.

¿Alguien conoce una forma de poder asignar el formato desde el texto xml en lugar desde la plantilla?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: David, esta pregunta parece escrita para StackOverflow (en inglés), para que sea válida aquí debes traducirla al español o será cerrada

Comment: disculpa, soy nuevo en stackoverflow y pensaba que eran comunes ambos foros. Gracias por el aviso.